# Geometry - really hard trapezium problem.

Tags: geometry, area

Can anyone explain me how to find the area of this trapezium if we have a base and radius of the circle?

[image]

Comment: Do you know anything about the angles of the trapezoid?  Two of them look like right angles, can we assume that?  If not, I don't think it has a unique solution.

Comment: No, only the base b and the radius (the only angles I know are 2 angles on the left, they are right angles because this is a right trapezium).My teacher somehow solved the problem this way http://i.imgur.com/ayVlWe5.png  he found out that HF and FI equal 1 and after a while he made an equation which contained x+1 and x-1, that's all i remember.

Comment: Something is wrong, you can shift the top to the left and maintain  the right angle with the radius and maintain parallel top and bottom, yet making the right side as long as you want.  So the trapezoid could have arbitrarily large area.

Comment: The two angles on the left need not be right angles to maintain a trapezoid, you just need to maintain two parallel sides.  A trapezoid does not need to have any right angles.

Comment: If the angle are assumed to be 90 as shown is diagram then the area can be $\dfrac{rb^2}{b-r}$ and hoping no careless mistake ofcouse.

Comment: Assuming the two angles are right, this is solvable using the Pitot theorem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_theorem.  Let $x$ be the length of the non-$b$ base in excess of 3 such that the length of that base is $3 + x$.  Then $3 + 3 + x = 4 + \sqrt{x^2 + 16}$.

Comment: Mann that is correct but how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you know a little more than just the top base and the radius.
[image: trapezium]
Using the letters in the plot that you attached in the comment, you also know

- that the circle is inscribed in the trapezium
- that the angles in D and C are right angles
- that the angle AIF is right too
- that the height DC is 2r
- that the segment HF=1, because it is $CF-r=3-2$

Since the circle is inscribed in the polygon, the two angles $\widehat{FAI}$ and $\widehat{HAF}$ are equal and so are the two triangles, since you also know that $AH=AI$ and $AF$ is shared. So, since the two triangles are equal, the two segments $HF$ and $FI$ are qual too, giving $IF=b-r=1$.

Now, name $x$ the piece of the lower base that we need to find, $x=GE$. If you draw the perpendicular form A to the side DE and, as before, draw also the bisector of the angle $\widehat{GEF}$ you will see (with an argument identical to the previous one) that $IE=x+b-r=x+1$, so that the hypotenuse $FE=x+2(b-r)=x+2$.

Using Pythagora's theorem for the triangle GEF you will have:

$$x^2+4^2=(x+2)^2$$
or in more general terms
$$x^2+(2r)^2=(x+2(b-r))^2$$

This means 
$$x=\frac{r^2-(b-r)^2}{b-r}=3$$

which is in agreement with what obtained with the Pitot theorem, mentioned by others.

Finally, your area is

$$A=2r\frac{b+(b+x)}{2}=18$$
in agreement with Mann's comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**

For every pair of tangents meeting at a point $A$, $AB=AB'$, where $B,B'$ are the tangential points.

**Problem**

Let $GC=a$ and $G'E=u$. Applying the theorem we have $BG=BH=3-a$, $GC=G'C=a$,
$G'E=H'E=u$ and $HD=H'D=a+1$. Notice $BH=GA\implies a=1$.

Observe $CE^2=(GH')^2+(u-a)^2\implies(u+1)^2=4^2+(u-1)^2\implies u=4$.

The area is $\displaystyle \frac{4[3+(a+1+u)]}{2}=18$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the crummy drawing (I wouldn't object if someone replaced it with a better one!), but hopefully it gets the point across:

[image]

The key triangles are similar, so

$${L\over r}={r\over b-r}$$

This gives $L=r^2/(b-r)$, so the area of the trapezium is

$${1\over2}(2r)(b+(r+L))=r\left(b+r+{r^2\over b-r}\right)={rb^2\over b-r}$$

Answer (score 0):

area of the trapezium is 
$$=(r)(2r)+(r)(b-r)+(r)\left(\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{b^2+r^2-2br}}\right)=r^2+br+\frac{r^3}{b-r}=\frac{rb^2}{b-r}$$
Now, setting the values $r=2$ & $b=3$, we get area of trapezium
$$=\frac{2(3)^2}{3-2}=18 \space sq. units$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar triangles, similar triangles...

[image]

Drawing lines out from the centre of the circle $O$ as shown, we see that

- $\triangle OEB$ and $\triangle OBF$ are congruent right triangles and also that
- $\triangle OFC$ and $\triangle OCG$ are congruent right triangles.

We can also see that $2\alpha + 2\beta$ forms a straight line, so - the key insight for me

- **$\alpha + \beta$ is a right angle**.

This means that $\triangle OBF, \triangle OBC$ and $\triangle OFC$ are all similar, and thus, since $|OE| = 2|EB|, \: |CG| = 2|OG| = 4$ and $|CD|=6$, giving the area of the trapezium:

$$\text{Area} = |AD|\frac{|AB|+|CD|}{2}= 4\frac{3+6}{2} = 18$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]
By Pythagoras’ Theorem, $$
\begin{aligned}
\because 4^{2}+(x-1)^{2}=(x+1)^{2} & \Leftrightarrow x=4 \\
\therefore \text { Area of the trapezium } &=\frac{1}{2}(4)(3+3) =18
\end{aligned}
$$